# Check whether if paraboloid of revolution reflect all the rays that strike it in one direction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In [[*part 5 Physical Applications of the Derivative as Slope* *of Chapter 4*]](https://books.google.com/books?id=tZy8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT169#v=onepage&q&f=false)  of *Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach(Second Edition)*, discussed the question about **What shape should a surface of revolution have in order to reflect in one direction all the rays that strike it?**

In [[this part]](https://books.google.com/books?id=tZy8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&lpg=PT171&dq=At+P+the+curve+behaves+as+though+it+were+replaced+by+the+tangent+at+P&source=bl&ots=uWMU4xuKoh&sig=60gKh3JxVWcRpNyVhWLWt0aRIaA&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2443_4tfaAhXnq1QKHTTsAQIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=At%20P%20the%20curve%20behaves%20as%20though%20it%20were%20replaced%20by%20the%20tangent%20at%20P&f=false) , the book concluded that

[image]

I am trying to seek the relation of $x$ and $y$ of the curve which could reflect all the rays that strike it in one direction according to the above conclusion, that is ∠1=∠2 and $\tan\angle 2 = \frac{1}{f^{'}\left( x \right)}$ where $f^{'}\left( x \right)$ is the slope of the tangent at P(x,y) of the curve , while $\tan\angle 1 = \frac{f^{'}\left( x \right) - k_{\text{FP}}}{1 + f^{'}\left( x \right)k_{\text{FP}}}$ where $k_{\text{FP}}$ is the slope of FP, ∠1=∠2 leads to $\tan\angle 1 = \tan\angle 2$.

I want to check if $\tan\angle 1 = \tan\angle 2$ holds in the [[parabola case]](https://books.google.com/books?id=tZy8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT174#v=onepage&q&f=false) , where $\tan\angle 2 = \frac{1}{f^{'}\left( x \right)} = \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2p}} = \frac{2p}{x}$ and $\tan\angle 1 = \frac{f^{'}\left( x \right) - k_{\text{FP}}}{1 + f^{'}\left( x \right)k_{\text{FP}}} = \frac{\frac{x}{2p} - \frac{\frac{x^{2}}{4p} - p}{x}}{1 + \frac{x}{2p} \cdot \frac{\frac{x^{2}}{4p} - p}{x}}$,however , [I cannot simply $\tan\angle 1$ to equal to $\tan\angle 2$](http://I%20cannot%20simply%20$%5Ctan%5Cangle%201$%20to%20equal%20to%20$%5Ctan%5Cangle%202$), that’s the problem , so what’s wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you’re most of the way there. I don’t see why you can’t simply equate the two tangents at this point in your proof. The angles are clearly measured in compatible directions, as you can see if you extend the ray $\overline{FP}$ and examine the opposite angle to $\angle1$. The horrible expression that you have for $\tan{\angle1}$ eventually simplifies to $\frac x{2p}$ as required.

Another way to verify the equality of the angles without quite as much messy algebraic manipulation is to show that the tangent at $P$ bisects the angle between $FP$ and $FD$. This is quite straightforward to do using vectors. For $x\gt0$ a direction vector of $FP$ is $\mathbf v = \left(x,{x^2\over4p}-p\right)$ and the direction of $FD$ is simply $\mathbf w = (0,1)$. Their angle bisector is $$\|\mathbf w\|\mathbf v - \|\mathbf v\|\mathbf w = \left(x,{x^2\over4p}-p+\sqrt{x^2+\left({x^2\over4p}-p\right)^2}\right) = \left(x,{x^2\over2p}\right) = x\left(1,{x\over2p}\right).\tag{*}$$ The direction vector of the tangent at $P$ is $(1,f')=\left(1,{x\over2p}\right)$. By symmetry, this bisector relationship also holds for $x\lt0$.

Comment: I sloved it myself . The trick is not rush to substitute $y$ in $\tan\angle 1 = \frac{f^{'}\left( x \right) - k_{\text{FP}}}{1 + f^{'}\left( x \right)k_{\text{FP}}}$ where $k_{FP}=(y-p)/x$ with ${\frac{x^{2}}{4p}}$ at first, and ${x^{2}}=4py$ , this could simplify the algebraic manipulation  a bit. Thanks anyway !